# How to limit number of turtles in a patch in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I want to limit number of turtles per patch. I thought if I restrict movement of turtles as per the (1) and (2) conditions it will limit number of turtles per patch but whatever code I tried for this till now did not worked.

[image]

Let's suppose there are five turtles on patch Y and five is the limit.

1) to ask turtles standing at front on patch X (refer figure) to stop moving till there are five turtles on patch Y (refer figure).

2) to ask turtles standing at front on patch Y to move forward to patch z (refer figure) if patch z has less than five(5) turtles on it else stop.

At last I am using following simple code

```
  let turtles-ahead other turtles in-cone speed 90
  let turtle-ahead min-one-of turtles-ahead [distance myself]
  ifelse turtle-ahead != nobody
  [
      set speed [speed] of turtle-ahead
      slow-down
  ]
  [speed-up]
```

This code simply ask turtles to move one-behind-another pattern or queue but it does not help me to limit number of turtles per patch whatever limit may be 4,5,6,7, 8... I have sprouted turtles within "go" procedures (1 turtle per patch, as per my need). The turtles are sprouted on a defined set of patches not in the whole world. So slowly number of turtles starts increasing and move around the world and after certain amount of ticks they are ask to exit out of the defined area and they die. Now at times it shows 10,11,.... 37 or above turtles on certain patches and this I want to stop actually.

I have checked one-turtles-per-patch, other code examples and many other helps from internet but no results.

For any other idea or help I would be obliged. Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to have turtles assess the `count` of `turtles-here` of the patch to which they are trying to move. Consider this simple example:

```
to setup
  ca
  ask n-of 15 patches with [ pycor = 0 ] [
    sprout 3 [
      set heading 90 
    ]
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask turtles [
    if ( count [turtles-here] of patch-ahead 1 ) < 5 and xcor < 16 [
      fd 1
    ]
  ]
  print [count turtles-here] of patches with [ any? turtles-here ]
  tick
end
```

On each tick, the turtles with an `xcor` of less than 16 (just to set a stop for this example) all check the `patch-ahead 1` for the count of turtles on that patch. If the count is less than 5, the turtle moves to that patch. Otherwise, the turtle does nothing.